# Flash images traped behind white boxes

Tags: flash, actionscript, wsdl, swfobject, crossdomain.xml

I am having that problem that on my page. My images are traped under some white boxes.

See it live here: http://kjacobsen.dk click on Archive

Anyone that know what is causing this problem?

The flash is loaded with SWFObject v1.4.4 with XML 1.0

Here is a part of the index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var so = new SWFObject("swf/kj.swf", "KJ", "100%", "100%", "8", "#000000");
    so.addVariable("xmlPath", "xml/publish.xml");
    so.addParam("scale", "noscale");
    so.addParam("allowScriptAccess", "sameDomain");
    so.addParam("menu", "false");
    so.addParam("loop", "false");
    so.addParam("salign", "lt");
    so.addParam("align", "left");
    so.write("flashcontent");

</script>
```

Comment: do you mean in the archive section (nice design, btw)?

Comment: Yes I do mean the archive section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour looks like you got an ordering issue.
I would check first the order in which addChild is added (unlikely)

MORE LIKELY:

### Loader issue?:

It almost looks like the **video** is set to be the **border**, and the **border** was set to be the **video**. Double check your settings to see if everything is pointing to the correct location / variable.

### Security Issue?:

It may be a security exception. Because you have hosted your files on amazon (images, movies) and the swf is on a different server.
The easy fix. Place your swf file in the same bucket on amazon s3, that way the domain reads the asset served from the **exact same host** that serves the **Flash application** itself. If that fixes the problem then it was a security exception that was getting thrown.

Comment: Where can I see these variables ?

Comment: Do you have the source code for it? Maybe they provided variables that you use to setup the environment, maybe its configured via an XML document, I don't know what you are using. Maybe you can provide more information.

Comment: I think it is in the XML because it before had worked with some local paths. Here is the new XML http://www.kjacobsen.dk/xml/publish.xml

Comment: And the old one that did work: http://www.kjacobsen.dk/publish.xml I cannot use it because my files are hosted on Amazon S3

Comment: Where is it most likely that the border have been set?

Comment: The XML looks fine. This is one of those situations where you need to find a time, server, situation where it worked and then change one variable at a time until it stops working. Does it work on another server setup? Maybe the server is gzipped and the way the images are loaded breaks the calculation (when a server is gzipped, swf no longer knows what the file size is, so totalbytes is zero, and when calculating percent, you would get a divide by zero, an exception thrown ... maybe that could be the cause).

Comment: The only really dramatic server change is that the files are not loaded locally that they before have.

Comment: what do you mean locally? Are the images now called from ANOTHER server? maybe you need a crossdomain file, maybe its a security exception.

Comment: Yes the images are called from another server in the XML file (Amazon S3) What type of crossdomain file do I need? And why are the movies loading without problems and front images. But why are there this problem with archive that uses the thumb images? :)

Comment: You can load images and movies BUT if you manipulate them then you would require a crossdomain file on the amazon server, which would be impractical. You need to run in debug mode and see if your app is throwing a security exception before you start going down this path.

Comment: In my logs I can see the thumb images are being called with GET and retrieved. How do I create a crossdomain file on the amazon server?

Comment: Updated my answer ... If its a security issue, the easy fix is to try to place the SWF as well on amazon S3 server.

Comment: I want to thank you for your help and fast response time. Do you have an e-mail to contact you with? :)

Comment: I use gmail.com, just add my username that you see here(dont want spambots to scrap my email, I already get enough spam as it is :) )